# XSLT: Using variables in a key function

Tags: xslt

I have a following XML file:

```
<titles>
   <book title="XML Today" author="David Perry"/>
   <book title="XML and Microsoft" author="David Perry"/>
   <book title="XML Productivity" author="Jim Kim"/>
   <book title="XSLT 1.0" author="Albert Jones"/>
   <book title="XSLT 2.0" author="Albert Jones"/>
   <book title="XSLT Manual" author="Jane Doe"/>
</titles>
```

I want to eliminate some elements and apply the following XSLT:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="author1-search" match="book[starts-with(@author, 'David')]" use="@title"/>
  <xsl:template match="book [key('author1-search', @title)]" />

  <xsl:key name="author2-search" match="book[starts-with(@author, 'Jim')]" use="@title"/>
  <xsl:template match="book [key('author2-search', @title)]" />

  <xsl:template match="/">  
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Is it possible to use an inline xsl variable

```
  <xsl:variable name="Author"> 
    <name>David</name> 
    <name>Jim</name> 
  </xsl:variable>
```

instead of "author1-search", "author2-search", and so on to loop through names?

I can use only XSLT 1.0 (2.0 is currently not supported).

Thanks in advance,

Leo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No, patterns (in XSLT 1.0) cannot contain variable/parameter references**.

**One way to perform such a task would be like this**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:param name="pAuthor" select="'David Perry'"/>

    <xsl:key name="kBookaByAuthor" match="book"
             use="@author"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">

     Books written by <xsl:value-of select="$pAuthor"/> :<xsl:text/>
        <xsl:apply-templates
             select="key('kBookaByAuthor', $pAuthor)"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="book">
     <!-- One can do more formatting here -->
     <xsl:text>&#xA;     </xsl:text>
     <xsl:value-of select="@title"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<titles>
    <book title="XML Today" author="David Perry"/>
    <book title="XML and Microsoft" author="David Perry"/>
    <book title="XML Productivity" author="Jim Kim"/>
    <book title="XSLT 1.0" author="Albert Jones"/>
    <book title="XSLT 2.0" author="Albert Jones"/>
    <book title="XSLT Manual" author="Jane Doe"/>
</titles>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
Books written by David Perry :
  XML Today
  XML and Microsoft
```

**Update**: In a comment the OP has clarified that:

> "*I thought I fully specified my requirements in the initial question.
>   As I mentioned in my question and in my first comment, it would be
>   helpful to me to see the approach for dealing with more than one
>   author*"

**Here is a solution that *truly* uses keys** (note that the "key" in the answer by @Flynn1179 doesn't build any index and is just a constant sequence of strings-- so the function `key()` using that `xsl:key` is actually finding a string in a list of strings -- which is O(N) as contrasted to, typically, O(1) for searching in a true index):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common">

     <xsl:output method="text"/>

     <xsl:param name="pAuthors">
      <x>David Perry</x>
      <x>Jane Doe</x>
     </xsl:param>

     <xsl:variable name="vParams" select=
      "ext:node-set($pAuthors)/*"/>

     <xsl:key name="kBookByAuthor" match="book"
                     use="@author"/>

     <xsl:template match="/">
       Books written by : <xsl:text/>

       <xsl:apply-templates select="$vParams"/>

       <xsl:apply-templates select=
        "key('kBookByAuthor', $vParams)"/>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="book">
       <!-- One can do more formatting here -->
       <xsl:text>&#xA;     </xsl:text>
       <xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;', @title, '&quot;')"/>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="x">
      <xsl:if test="not(position() = 1)">, </xsl:if>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
     </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied to the provided XML document (above), the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
   Books written by : David Perry, Jane Doe
     "XML Today"
     "XML and Microsoft"
     "XSLT Manual"
```

**Do note**: In this solution the Exslt function `node-set()` is used. **This is done only for convenience here**. In a real usage, the value of the parameter will be specified externally and then the `ext:node-set()` function isn't necessary.

**Efficiency**: This solution uses the true power of keys in XSLT. An experiment made using MSXML (3, 4 and 6) XSLT processors shows that if we search for 10000 authors the transformation time with different XSLT processors ranges from: 32ms to 45ms.

**Interestingly, the solution presented by @Flynn1179 doesn't indeed make key index and with many XSLT processors it takes (for the same number (10000) of authors) from 1044ms to 5564ms**:

**MSXML3**: 5564 ms.,

**MSXML4**: 2526ms,

**MSXML6**: 4867 ms,

**AltovaXML**: 1044ms.

This is *quite inferior* to the performance one gets with true key indexing (32ms to 45ms).

Comment: Hello Dimitre, Thanks a lot for your prompt reply. In your sample you specifed just one author. What would you recommend if I need to specify several authors in an inline xsl (as mentioned in my question)? Is there any way to avoid explicitly setting a parameter to 'David Perry'? You argue that the suggested apporach is just one way to perform this task. Which alternatives (perhaps, supporting at least some sort of iteration) can be taken into consideration?

Comment: @Leo68: You must edit the question, or better, ask a new question, fully specifying your new requirements. Keys are powerful enough for searching on multiple authors. As for the parameter, it isn't "explicitly set". A global `xsl:param` is usually set externally, by the code that invokes the transformation (or as a command-line argument). What is specified in the `select` attribute is just the *default* value for this parameter, in case it isn't set by the invoker of the transformation.

Comment: I thought I fully specified my requirements in the initial question. As I mentioned in my question and in my first comment, it would be helpful to me to see the approach for dealing with more than one author and to figure out if at least some kind of iteration is possible here.

Comment: @Leo68: No, the text of the question doesn't contain a requirement to select any book written by a set of authors -- the wanted result also shows books by just one author -- please either edit this question, or, better, ask a new question. A good question provides this information: 1. The well-formed source XML document (as small as possible). 2. The wanted result. 3. An explanation of the requirements that the transformation must implement.

Comment: @Leo68: I have updated my answer to fully meet your latest requirement.

Comment: @Dimitre: Aside from the fact your claims about the efficiency of my answer (and yours) are untrue (I think you've mixed up my two solutions), your latest solution is in fact, wrong. It won't use anything passed into the parameter, it'll continue to use the defaults specified in the stylesheet.

Comment: @Flynn1179: You would be certain to say this if in your solution `<my:authors>` contained thousands of children and then your transformation wouldn't be noticeably slower that using keys in the proper way. As for my using embedded global `xsl:param` -- this is just for convenience. In a real practical case the current contents of this parameter would reside in a separate XML document, and the parameter (if used) would contain the URI to this document. Perhaps I should change `xsl:param` to something else to avoid such confusion.

Comment: No, I think you just mixed up my solutions: One of them uses a static string, the OTHER uses xsl:key, and is a lot faster than O(N). As for yours being O(1), that's clearly impossible. No search O(1) search algorithm exists.

Comment: @Flynn1179: You may extend your knowledge, which will help you be more accurate when making absolute statements... Do read about hash tables and their efficiency. Most XSLT processors implement a key index as a hash table. Again, you may easily check this empirically. Extend the number of children of `$pAuthors` from my answer -- 100 times and verify that the response time hasn't increased 100 times and is the same as when `$pAuthors` has only two children`. :)

Comment: @Flynn1179: Yes I made a quick experiment (using msxml4) -- your solution is not even O(N) but seems to be O(N^2) where N is the number of `my:authors/my:name` elements in your solution and `David Perry` and `Jim Kim` are the las two of these. For N = 1000 the elapsed time is 26ms, for N=10000 the elapsed time is 2526ms.

Comment: @Dimitre: I already did before posting that, the most efficient algorithm for searching a hashtable is O(1+n/k), not O(1). Take your own advice, please, and stop splitting hairs over seriously irrelevant points; the list has two items in it, efficiency is extremely unlikely to be a consideration.

Comment: @Flynn1179: That your solution is inefficient is not "splitting hairs" here are some results of going from N=1000 to N=10000. MSXML3: from 56ms to 5564 ms., MSXML4: from 26ms to 2526ms, MSXML6: from 49 ms to 4867 ms, AltovaXML: from 108ms to 1044ms. This is O(N) in the case of AltovaXML and O(N^2) in the case of the three MSXML proceccors.

Comment: Why the heck are you wasting so much of your time on this? There isn't 1000 or 10000 in the list, there's TWO! Maybe a few more than that in practice, but still not nearly enough to matter to anyone. I can think of plenty other reasons for that performance fall-off that are nothing to do with the lookup as well (merely loading a stylesheet of that size, for example), but I really don't think it's worth debating. The efficiency doesn't matter in this case.

Comment: @Flynn1179: Showing to the readers the issues in your solution is not "wasting so much time", neither is trying to open your eyes to these. As for the search in a hash-table being `O(n/k)`, this is so for tables with collisions, where `k` is the number of distinct values. In the case of keys, the mapping key --> value is most often 1:1, and that means `k = N` -- in all such cases the efficiency of a key lookup is O(1). The search the current question is asking for has a key search efficiency O(1).

Comment: No, Dimitre, it really is a waste of time. These 'issues' are virtually inconsequential, especially compared to the fact your solution actually didn't work at all at the time. Please, try to grasp that it's up to the OP to determine what the best answer for them is, not you. Pointing out incredibly trivial inefficiencies like this is just rude, and a waste of everybody's time.

Comment: @Flynn1179: Besides the significant lower performance, you demonstrate a fake use of `xsl:key`, where the expression specified in the `use` attribute is not a function at all of the node being matched. And of course, this is the reason for the bad performance. My comments are made in order to alert the reader that this is a fake and bad use of the `xsl:key` instruction, that has nothing to do with the idea of keying (as no index is produced at all).

Comment: Given that it works, I'd dispute the rather offensive use of the term 'fake', but I'll accept that yeah, it's going to be less efficient than I thought it would, although it still doesn't matter. Anyway, I'm not making that point AGAIN, because it's clearly not sinking in.

Comment: @Flynn1179: Great progress! The main thing is not what *you* thing about your solution, but that it shows to the users an antipattern for using `xsl:key`, and this needs to be pointed out. The inefficiency, of course, results from this antipattern.

Answer (score 2):

Patterns in XSLT 1.0 are not allowed to contain variable or parameter references so you couldn't use variable or parameter references in those key definitions or in the template match attributes you have.

Comment: Thanks Martin, so, in your opinion, when using XSLT 1.0 I have to specify xsl:key name="author1-search", xsl:key name="author2-search", and so on?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using variables, you could just include an element in your XSLT sheet in it's own namespace, and refer to that, like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:my="my:my">
  <xsl:key name="authors" use="document('')/*/my:authors/my:name" match="/" />

  <my:authors> 
    <my:name>David Perry</my:name>
    <my:name>Jim Kim</my:name> 
  </my:authors>

  <xsl:template match="book[not(key('authors',@author))]" />

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The `book` template matches those that do NOT have a corresponding `my:name` element for their author, and outputs nothing. The identity template outputs everything else, including the book elements you DO care about. The key's a bit of a hack, it essentially matches the whole document where the name exists, rather than matching the `my:name` element that matches. Since you only care about it's existence, this shouldn't be a problem.

Alternatively, if you'd rather be able to pass in a list of authors, you can use this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:param name="authors" select="'David Perry,Jim Kim'" />

  <xsl:template match="book">
    <xsl:if test="contains(concat(',',$authors,','),concat(',',@author,','))">
      <xsl:call-template name="identity" />
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()" name="identity">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The variable's used in an `<xsl:if>` rather than in the template match, but it does the same job. This particular code needs the list of authors specified as a comma separated list, but it should be easy enough to adapt it if you'd rather use a different format.