# XSLT: Using variables in a key function (cont.)

Tags: xslt

I have a following XML file:

```
<titles> 
   <book title="XML Today" author="David Perry"/> 
   <book title="XML and Microsoft" author="David Perry"/> 
   <book title="XML Productivity" author="Jim Kim"/> 
   <book title="XSLT 1.0" author="Albert Jones"/> 
   <book title="XSLT 2.0" author="Albert Jones"/> 
   <book title="XSLT Manual" author="Jane Doe"/> 
</titles>
```

and the transformation to eliminate the elements with @author starting with 'David' or 'Jane':

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="author1-search" match="book[starts-with(@author, 'David')]" use="@title"/>
  <xsl:template match="book [key('author1-search', @title)]" />

  <xsl:key name="author2-search" match="book[starts-with(@author, 'Jane')]" use="@title"/>
  <xsl:template match="book [key('author2-search', @title)]" />

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()" name="identity">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The expected result will be the following XML file:

```
<titles> 
   <book title="XML Productivity" author="Jim Kim"/> 
   <book title="XSLT 1.0" author="Albert Jones"/> 
   <book title="XSLT 2.0" author="Albert Jones"/> 
</titles>
```

In his reply to the [XSLT: Using variables in a key function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9034175/xslt-using-variables-in-a-key-function) question Dimitre Novatchev has shown the method to use iteration to display books written by the selected authors using keys and the Exslt function node-set() with the inline xsl parameter

```
  <xsl:param name="pAuthors"> 
      <x>David Perry</x> 
      <x>Jane Doe</x> 
     </xsl:param>
```

Is it possible to apply this method to rewrite the transformation above so that it would use the pAuthors parameter and contain just one generic search key (instead of author1-search, author2-search, and so on)? XSLT 2.0 and the document() function are not supported.

Thanks in advance, Leo

Comment: What the difference between current question and previous?

Comment: @Leo68: What do you mean "contain just one generic search key"? I think that I answered your previous question completely. What new requirements do you have now? Please, define the new requirements and show us an example.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev As I mentioned in my question, your example allows to display books written by the selected authors. My task is to eliminate several elements from the above xml. In the sample xslt I use several keys to attain this goal; the question is how to rewrite this xslt using the inline xsl parameter pAuthors
and just one generic key instead of author1-search, author2-search, and so on. Thanks a lot for your help, Leo

Comment: In my quesion I clearly stated that I want to rewrite the sample XSLT, which eliminates the elements with the @author starting with 'David' or 'Jane', using a single generic key and the pAuthors parameter. The expected result is the xml file containing <book title="XML Productivity" author="Jim Kim"/>  
   <book title="XSLT 1.0" author="Albert Jones"/>  
   <book title="XSLT 2.0" author="Albert Jones"/> , as can be inferred from applying the sample XSLT to the XML file. I also provided further explanations in my reply to your comment. Which other information do you need?

Comment: @Leo68: No, you didn't say this in the question. You are saying this now and only in a comment and only when asked. This information can be guessed looking at the provided code, but relying on reader's guesses means the question isn't well-formulated. Please, edit the question and explicitly provide the needed information. Remember, most of the time your code may not be really important and may be misleading -- what is really needed is the source XML document, the wanted result and the requirements for the transformation.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev: Following your advice, I have edited my question. Yet, already in my initial question I have explicitly specified the source XML document, the wanted result (which could be easily inferred from the sample XSLT) and the requirements for the transformation...

Comment: @Leo68: And in the meantime I have posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From guesses looking in the code, I believe, the OP is how to use XSLT keys in helping eliminate books written by any author from a given set of authors.

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:param name="pAuthors">
        <x>David Perry</x>
        <x>Jane Doe</x>
    </xsl:param>

    <xsl:variable name="vParams" select=       "
      ext:node-set($pAuthors)/*"/>

  <xsl:key name="kBookByAuthor" match="book"
           use="@author"/>  

  <xsl:variable name="vBooksToExclude" select=
   "key('kBookByAuthor', $vParams)"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="book">
  <xsl:if test="count(.|$vBooksToExclude) != count($vBooksToExclude)">
    <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<titles>
    <book title="XML Today" author="David Perry"/>
    <book title="XML and Microsoft" author="David Perry"/>
    <book title="XML Productivity" author="Jim Kim"/>
    <book title="XSLT 1.0" author="Albert Jones"/>
    <book title="XSLT 2.0" author="Albert Jones"/>
    <book title="XSLT Manual" author="Jane Doe"/>
</titles>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result, in which any book that has an author from the provided set of authors (David Perry and Jane Doe), is skipped**:

```
<titles>
   <book title="XML Productivity" author="Jim Kim"/>
   <book title="XSLT 1.0" author="Albert Jones"/>
   <book title="XSLT 2.0" author="Albert Jones"/>
</titles>
```

**Explanation**:

We use the following XPath expression to determine whether a node `$n` doesn't belong to a node-set `$s`:

```
count($n | $s) != count($s)
```

**Final update**:

As the OP wants, here we exclude from copying to the output all books, that have an author, whose first name is provided as one of many values in an external/global parameter. **We still use a single key.**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:param name="pAuthors">
        <x>David</x>
        <x>Jane</x>
    </xsl:param>

    <xsl:variable name="vParams" select=       "
      ext:node-set($pAuthors)/*"/>

  <xsl:key name="kBookByAuthor" match="book"
           use="substring-before(@author, ' ')"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vBooksToExclude" select=
   "key('kBookByAuthor', $vParams)"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="book">
  <xsl:if test="count(.|$vBooksToExclude) != count($vBooksToExclude)">
    <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document** (added another David author):

```
<titles>
    <book title="XML Today" author="David Perry"/>
    <book title="XML and Microsoft" author="David Perry"/>
    <book title="Just example" author="David Masters"/>
    <book title="XML Productivity" author="Jim Kim"/>
    <book title="XSLT 1.0" author="Albert Jones"/>
    <book title="XSLT 2.0" author="Albert Jones"/>
    <book title="XSLT Manual" author="Jane Doe"/>
</titles>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<titles>
  <book title="XML Productivity" author="Jim Kim" />
  <book title="XSLT 1.0" author="Albert Jones" />
  <book title="XSLT 2.0" author="Albert Jones" />
</titles>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it seems to be the way to solve this problem. In my sample and initial question I actually wanted to eliminate authors whose names start with (or, perhaps, contain) David or Jane. How would you update your transformation to do so?

Comment: @Leo68: In XSLT 2.0 this is easy. I have to think about an XSLT 1.0 solution and this doesn't seem to have an obvious solution using a single, statically defined key. The non-key solution is very obvious.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. Alas, I can use only XSLT 1.0. Of course, I would highly appreciate seeing the solution with a single key, since I have to eliminate a number of elements from the XML file. If you think it is too complex, perhaps, it would be possible to outline the non-key solution using the pAuthors parameter?

Comment: Dimitre: Thank you very much! I appreciate your elegant solution; yet, it seems that it addresses just a particular case when the author name contains a white space between the first and family names. I wonder if it is possible to use a single key and specify <x>David</x> in the pAuthors parameter if @author can have a value "David.Perry", "David&Perry", or "Davidson". In other words, is it possible to eliminate the authors starting with 'David' (or even better containing 'David')? If a solution with a single key appears too complex, perhaps, there is a non-key solution using XSLT 1.0?

Comment: @Leo68: Of course, there is a non-key solution. If you ask this as a separate question, most people will be able to provide an answer.

Comment: Dimitre: Do you think the solution which uses a single key is possible as well?

Comment: @Leo68: As long as a single relative XPath expression exists that specifies the key as a function of the matched (indexed) node. If such XPath expression requires some additional variable, then this isn't possible to do with a single key.