# XSLT: How to get a key from current page's items only (Umbraco)?

Tags: xslt, umbraco

I'm using XSL in Umbraco to try and get a list of items associated with the current node. This list of items is built from the "Embedded Content" plugin content type. I've got this far:

`<xsl:key name="key-name" match="listOfItems/data/item" use="itemKeyName" />`

But this selects the `listOfItems` from **all** Umbraco nodes. Basically, I want the key to match `$currentPage/listOfItems/data/item` but as I can't use variables in the `xsl:key`, how can I achieve this?

Comment: There are some alternatives here if you are using XSLT 1.0: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9034175/xslt-using-variables-in-a-key-function

Answer (score 0):

There are several XSLT examples for Umbraco tree traversal here:

http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/xslt/xpath-axes-and-their-shortcuts